# Download And Mail Excel File Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a database full of users, on the backend I have a button to collect my database and download it as a Excel file. (Using Maatwebsite). At the same time I want the admin to receive an email with this Excel file. How do I add this fiel to the email?
This is the code:

```
public function excel()
{
    Excel::create('Participants', function($excel) {

        $excel->sheet('Participants', function($sheet) {

            $sheet->fromArray(Participant::where('enabled',1)->get(), null, 'A1', false, false);

        });
    })->download("xlsx");
    Mail::raw("In attachment excelfile of participants ", function($message)
    {
        $message->subject('ExcelFile Participants!');
        $message->from('no-reply@asadventurecontest.be', 'As Adventure Contest');
        $message->to('admin@mywebsite.com');
        //$message->attachData(, 'Participants.xlsx');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store your Excel file and attach it with your mail
[cf. Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#attachments).
For store your Excel, you can use the function 'store' :  [Laravel Excel Store](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export).

After that, you can delete it or keep it.